# Why is new Node is not added?

Tags: java, oop, linked-list, nodes

```
public class LinkedList {


    static Node head;

    static class Node{
        int data;
        Node next;

        Node(int dat){
            data = dat;
            next = null;
        }

    }

    public void add(int data){
        Node node = new Node(data);
        Node n = head;
        while (n!= null){
            n = n.next;
        }
        n = node;

    }

    public void print(){
        Node n = head;

        while(n!=null){
            System.out.println(n.data);
            n = n.next;
        }
    }
}
```

I realize that in the add() method I am assigning 'node' to an item that has the value null, however, the doubt is even is n.next becomes null its still a node right because 'next' is defined as a Node, so it should work right.

Comment: You never actually change the list. You just make a new node, set it aside, and then look at all of the elements in your list in order. You need to actually change some pointers somewhere if you want your data structure's contents to be altered.

Comment: i dont understand your statement!can u pls explain it in a simple way

Comment: Yousaf beat me to it. His answer is what I was in the process of typing out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add the new node at the end of the linked list, you need to take following steps:

1. Create the new node
2. Check if linked list is empty. If it is, point the `head` to the new node and return from the function
3. If linked list is not empty, traverse the linked list until the last node is reached
4. Point the `next` of the last node to the new node created in step 1.

#### Problem

There are couple of problems in your code:

1. You are not handling the special case of adding the new node in the empty linked list
2. `while` loop in the `add()` method doesn't stops when the last node is reached. It only stops when `n` itself becomes `null` which means you cannot add the new node in the linked list

#### Solution

You need to change the condition in the `while` loop from

```
n != null
```

to

```
n.next != null
```

to make sure that you are at the last node in the linked list after the loop ends and then to add the new node in the linked list, you need to point the `next` of the last node to the new node

```
n.next = node;
```

Your `add()` method should be written as:

```
public void add(int data) {
    Node node = new Node(data);

    if (head == null) {
       head = node;
       return;
    }

    Node n = head;

    while (n.next != null){
        n = n.next;
    }

    n.next = node;
}
```

Comment: Plus a special case for when `head == null` (i.e. when we're adding the first element to the list). But otherwise, this looks good.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo yes, you are right. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: but the question is even if its value is null its still a node right? so we should be able to assign it  a new node

Comment: @GauravRajput You need to ask yourself a question: "What do i need to do to add a node at the end of the linked list?". Answer is that you need to set the `next` of the last node to the new node but the problem with `n != null` condition is that when the loop ends, `n` is `null` so `n = node` means that instead of adding the new node in the linked list, you are saving the reference of the new node in the `n` which is of type `Node`.